# Type convert in C++

Tags: c++

```
double number =10.9
int a ;
a = (int)number ;a = int(number) ;
```

1. what are the difference between  **int()** and **(int)** to convert de type into **int**
2. if  i use my own class BASE ;   BASE() ;  (BASE)  ;   what the difference?which is faster or unexpensive(cheap)?

Comment: `int(number)` and `(int)number` are two different ways in C++ of achieving the same thing.     Similar answer for user-defined classes, as long as the class supports a suitable constructor (or the expression being converted has a conversion operator).

Comment: `(int)` is the c way. `int()` is the c++ way. `xxx_cast<>()` is the modern c++ way.

Comment: @zdf - That's an opinion pushed by some.    The `xxx_cast`s are more fine-grained and there are certainly use cases where they are preferable (e.g. catching some hard-to-detect errors that sail past the C-style cast or C++ function style cast).   Declaring them as the "modern C++ way", particularly for a simple conversion between `double` and `int` where the errors won't occur,  is bordering on zealotry though.

Comment: @Peter Right, but I do not see a simpler way to explain it.